# t-sql Odd Join Requirement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Sorry for the strange title but I'm having a difficult time thinking of something more descriptive.

I need to know how you'd accomplish the following thing in T-SQL:

Imagine you have the following 3 tables with the typical 1-to-many relationships you'd expect for these entities. Notice though "SpecialBooleanFlag" on the Items table (more on that in a moment):

```
Customers: CustomerId, CustomerName, (etc....)
Orders:    OrderId, OrderDtm, CustomerId (etc.....)
Items:     ItemId, ItemDescripion, OrderId, **SpecialBooleanFlag**
```

This sounds like an odd requirement and beyond my means to explain in this post, but imagine your boss asked you to write a query that returned all of a customer's complete order history with each item they've ever bought. However, if *just one* of a customer's orders has an item with SpecialBooleanFlag = 1, then make that item appear *as if* the customer had ordered the item on every order in their order history.

So, if a customer has never ordered an item with SpecialBooleanFlag = 1, then the result count should be equal to the total number of items they've ever ordered. However, if they've placed 5 orders and just one of those orders has an item with SpecialBooleanFlag = 1, then the result count would be 5 + 4, with the 4 extra rows associating the flagged item with the 4 orders which never really matched the item.

I accomplished this once already with a cursor/looping but the solution is too slow and I need to know a way to do it with plain old set operations if possible.

Edit: For example, imagine the following query/result set:

```
SELECT CustomerName as Name, CustomerId, OrderId, ItemDescription, SpecialBooleanFlag
FROM Customers C
JOIN Orders O on C.CustomerId = O.CustomerId
JOIN Items I on O.OrderId = I.OrderId
WHERE C.CustomerId = 99
```

Results:

```
CustomerName        CustomerId     OrderId      ItemDescription    SpecialBooleanFlag
George Washington   99             1            Shoes              0
George Washington   99             1            Shirt              0
George Washington   99             1            Tie                0
George Washington   99             2            Socks              0
George Washington   99             2            Hat                1     
George Washington   99             2            Bowtie             0
George Washington   99             3            Green Coat         0
George Washington   99             3            Blue Coat          0
George Washington   99             3            Red Coat           0
```

So, the customer has had 3 orders with 9 total items in all. The Hat is "special" though and was on order #2. I want it to appear as if was ordered each time. This result set is what I'm looking for. The hat shows up on orders 1 and 3 based on the fact that it was flagged rather than an association between the item and orderId's 1 and 3:

```
 CustomerName        CustomerId     OrderId      ItemDescription    SpecialBooleanFlag
    George Washington   99             1            Shoes              0
    George Washington   99             1            Shirt              0
    George Washington   99             1            Tie                0
    George Washington   99             1            Hat                1 
    George Washington   99             2            Socks              0
    George Washington   99             2            Hat                1     
    George Washington   99             2            Bowtie             0
    George Washington   99             3            Green Coat         0
    George Washington   99             3            Blue Coat          0
    George Washington   99             3            Red Coat           0
    George Washington   99             3            Hat                1
```

Does this make more sense?

Comment: show some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Are you looking for a count or a listing of the orders / items?

Comment: I'm looking for the listing of the orders / items. My last edit illustrates this.

Comment: It sounds like the special boolean flag constitutes a recurring order (otherwise, why would your boss want it included in every order?).  If this assumption is correct, you should modify your DB structure, associating those special items with the customer, instead of the order.  You could create another table to store them and modify any applications that interface with this data.  If this isn't the case, why the bizarre request?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Sean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 words, CROSS APPLY.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Customers') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Customers
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Orders') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Orders
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Items') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Items

CREATE TABLE #Customers ( CustomerId INT, CustomerName varchar(255) )
CREATE TABLE #Orders ( OrderId INT, OrderDtm DateTime, CustomerId INT )
CREATE TABLE #Items ( ItemId INT, ItemDescripion VARCHAR(255), OrderId INT, SpecialBooleanFlag BIT )

INSERT INTO #Customers ( CustomerId, CustomerName )
VALUES ( 1,'Customer1' )
,( 2,'Customer2' )
,( 3,'Customer3' )
,( 4,'Customer4' )

INSERT INTO #Orders ( OrderId, OrderDtm, CustomerId )
VALUES (1,'2016-01-01',1)
,(2,'2016-01-02',1)
,(3,'2016-01-03',1)
,(4,'2016-01-04',2)
,(5,'2016-01-05',2)
,(6,'2016-01-06',2)
,(7,'2016-01-07',3)
,(8,'2016-01-08',3)
,(9,'2016-01-09',3)
,(10,'2016-01-10',4)

INSERT INTO #Items ( ItemId, ItemDescripion, OrderId, SpecialBooleanFlag )
VALUES ( 1,'Order1Item1',1,0)
,( 2,'Order1Item2',1,0)
,( 3,'Order1Item3',1,0)
,( 1,'Order2Item1',2,0)
,( 2,'Order2Item2',2,0)
,( 1,'Order3Item1',3,0)
,( 1,'Order4Item1',4,0)
,( 2,'Order4Item2',4,0)
,( 3,'Order4Item3',4,1)
,( 1,'Order5Item1',5,0)
,( 2,'Order5Item2',5,0)
,( 1,'Order6Item1',6,0)

--DECLARE @CustomerId INT = 1 -- no SpecialBooleanFlag
DECLARE @CustomerId INT = 2 -- has SpecialBooleanFlag

SELECT C.CustomerId, C.CustomerName,O.OrderId,O.OrderDtm,I.ItemId,I.ItemDescripion,SpecialBooleanFlag
FROM #Customers C
JOIN #Orders O on C.CustomerId = O.CustomerId
JOIN #Items I on O.OrderId = I.OrderId
WHERE C.CustomerId = @CustomerId
AND SpecialBooleanFlag != 1
UNION
SELECT C.CustomerId, C.CustomerName,O2.OrderId,O.OrderDtm,I.ItemId,I.ItemDescripion,SpecialBooleanFlag
FROM #Customers C
JOIN #Orders O on C.CustomerId = O.CustomerId
JOIN #Items I on O.OrderId = I.OrderId
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT * FROM #Orders O2 WHERE O2.CustomerId = C.CustomerId ) O2
WHERE C.CustomerId = @CustomerId
AND SpecialBooleanFlag = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should work:

```
SELECT c.CustomerName, c.CustomerId, o.OrderId, i.ItemDescription, i.SpecialBooleanFlag
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN Orders o on c.CustomerId = o.CustomerId
LEFT JOIN Items i on o.OrderId = i.OrderId OR EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM orders o1 JOIN items i1 ON o1.OrderId = i1.OrderId
     WHERE o1.CustomerId = c.CustomerId 
       and i.ItemId = i1.ItemId 
       and i1.SpecialBooleanFlag = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  C.CustomerName AS Name,
        C.CustomerId,
        O.OrderId,
        I.ItemDescripion,
        I.SpecialBooleanFlag
FROM    #Customers C
        JOIN #Orders O ON C.CustomerId = O.CustomerId
        JOIN #Items I ON O.OrderId = I.OrderId
WHERE   C.CustomerId = 99
UNION   
SELECT  C.CustomerName AS Name,
        C.CustomerId,
        O.OrderId,
        I.ItemDescripion,
        I.SpecialBooleanFlag
FROM    #Customers C
        JOIN #Orders O ON C.CustomerId = O.CustomerId
        FULL OUTER JOIN #Items I ON I.SpecialBooleanFlag = 1
WHERE   C.CustomerId = 99
```